# FragmentBuilder issue after updating Android studio to 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

Today I did update Android Studio to 2.0. And I faced with the problem:

[image]

There weren't any problems with 1.5, but now there are. I'm using  `sockeqwe/fragmentargs` library to communicate between fragments using `FragmentBuilder`.

I have the latest version in `gradle`:

```
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:annotation:3.0.2'
apt 'com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:processor:3.0.2'
```

Also, I did update for gradle to 2.0.0.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but this problem is connected with `Instant Run` functionality. I disabled it and all are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDK Manager download and install all on SDK Platforms and SDK Tools this will solve your issue.